# Azure Pipeline - Unable to get Pytest to work

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a repository with selenium tests that I'm trying to create a Pipeline for. I want the pipeline to use Pytest to run one of the tests I have.

[repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUl5j.png)

However, when I run the pipeline, I get the below error saying

ERROR: file not found: tests

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe931.png)

I think it has something to do with what I'm putting in the pytest script section, but I'm not sure what is supposed to go in there. I've tried the PATH of the users_tests.py file and that doesn't work either.

[script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHL2a.png)

Would greatly appreciate any thoughts on how I can get this to work. My end goal is to use Azure Test Plans to run my selenium scripts.

Comment: please make sure you set correct working directory on yout pytest task

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Pipeline - Unable to get Pytest to work

When we use command line task directly, the **default work folder** for it is:

```
C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
```

Obviously, there are no files managed by our git in this directory. That the reason why you get the `ERROR: file not found: tests`

To run the pytest script in the command line task, we need to navigate to the directory of the test scripts file, like:

```
cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/xxx/xxx/Tests/home
```

For the `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory`, you could check the [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables) for some more details.